# How to split a strings letters instead of the words?

Tags: python, string

How do I split a string's letters? For example, I want 'Hello World' into 'h e l l o w o r l d'. I tried using the .split method but it only split the words, not all the characters. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: `list(mystring)`

Comment: ```' '.join(i.lower() if i != ' ' else '' for i in strng)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `join` and a generator expression:

```
strng = 'Hello World'
' '.join(i.lower() if i != ' ' else '' for i in strng)
```

Output:

```
'h e l l o  w o r l d'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
letters = [c for c in 'Hello World' if c != ' ']
```

Result:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Comment: this isn't the desired output

Comment: I interpreted the question as wanting to do something similar to what `split` does but on a letter-by-letter basis, and `split` returns a list. As to what output was desired, I don't think anyone but OP can be the final authority.

Comment: ' I want 'Hello World' into 'h e l l o w o r l d'.'?

Comment: Yep, that's what was written, and also "How do I split a string's letters?" I don't think a string that separates letters with single spaces has "split" them. There is some ambiguity in the question, and my answer reflects my interpretation given that ambiguity. I suppose your answer reflects your interpretation. But that doesn't make either of us an authority on what was the desired output.

Comment: yeah well in general if OP said I want this into that then I'd take that to mean they want that regardless of the terminology used in the rest of the question